# mootools asset not loading

Tags: javascript, mootools, google-ads-api

I'm trying to dynamically trigger a Google adwords conversion in a situation where the "success" page is the same page as the form page (reposts to the same page and sets a message). So I set the message and check for it with javascript, which then should load the adwords conversion js. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            var convmessage = null;
            convmessage = $('message');

            if(!!convmessage) {
                console.log("yo");
                if ($('message').getChildren()[1].innerText){
                    console.log("yoyo");        
                    var google_conversion_id        = 1234;
                    var google_conversion_language  = "en-US";
                    var google_conversion_format    = "1";
                    var google_conversion_color     = "ffffff";
                    var google_conversion_label     = "Label";

                    var myScript = Asset.javascript('http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', {
                        id: 'myScript',
                        onLoad: function(){
                            console.log("loaded");
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

When I submit the form, my console log reads
`yo`
`yoyo`
but never displays the `loaded` message. So it appears that the script should get loaded but never does, even though the script (apparently) executes properly.

Is there something I'm missing about using the mootools asset function, or another reason that the script doesn't get loaded?

Thanks

Comment: couple of things. assets works. the problem is with this script you're loading - from a brief look, it cant be lazyloaded as it does a document.write and that needs context to write at. also, `var google_conversion_id = ` will be scoped, needs to be global (`window.google_conversion_id`) - in other words, do it their way or the highway.

Comment: thanks dimitar-- I moved the asset load outside the if statements so it loads regardless of whether the vars are set, and set the vars to global. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was just checking this function on JS Fiddle, and It worked fine for me. Just not with your script.

It looks like Google is force downloading the script, which it looks like breaks the mootools script. I would try hosting that script on your own server or use another one.

You can see what I did here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9h8Zx/1/